# Calling multiple (python) functions from a single web page

Tags: flask, vue.js

I'm going through several tutorials on Flask and Vue and until now I've seen only the pattern, one route corresponding to one python function. What I would like to do is from a single web page (single route) be able to call multiple functions without reloading the page e.g. by pressing a button x call function x on the server and present the results on the same web page,  by pressing a button y call function y on the server and present the results on the same web page etc.

Is this possible and if yes how? (I mean tips not necessarily code)

Answer (score 1):

I think what are you searching for is Ajax Calls. 
you can specify for each action to trigger an Ajax Call to the server as each route has his own action in server ( Flask in your case ) for more details search for `REST API`.
 For that you can look to [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) library.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I found out how it works with jQuery. I'll try with Vue and Axios soon.